# How do I get current system time in IST format and compare it to a time in HH:mm:ss format (which is in String datatype)? solution in java language

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, date, time

```
SimpleDateFormat time_formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String current_time_str = time_formatter.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date currentTime = time_formatter.parse(current_time_str);
Date userTime = time_formatter.parse(timeSlots);
```

When I do this I am getting incorrect result as server time is in UTC format.

Comment: What is IST format?

Comment: Your question is quite vague. Rewrite to explain your objective. Are you trying to compare the time of day as seen in a particular time zone against a specified time of day?

Comment: Why the tags for Spring?

Comment: What do you meant by “UTC format”? [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is not a format.

Comment: IST - Indian Standard Time. I am getting the input in HH:mm:ss (datatype is string), I need to check if the inputted time has already passed or not.

Comment: Also the server time is in UTC, so my comparison is being mismatched.

Comment: Usage: There is no such thing as *IST format*. There are three or more time zones the time of which that may be abbreviated *IST* some or all of the year. India Standard Time is one of several reasonable interpretations of *IST*. On the other hand the *format* is `HH:mm:ss` and would work in any time zone.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly deisgned and therefore troublesome to work with, and they are long outdated. Use java.time, the omdern Java date and time API, and its `LocalTime` class. See the high-quality answer by Basil Bourque.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime
.parse( input )
.isBefore( 
    LocalTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) 
)
```

## Details

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use `SimpleDateFormat` or `Date`.

Capture the current moment as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Adjust to a time zone.

`IST` is not a real time zone. Such 2-4 letter abbreviations are merely a crude indicator of whether Daylight Saving Time (DST) is engaged or not for a region. These abbreviations are not standardized, they are not even unique! For example `IST` is commonly used to mean Ireland Standard Time as well as India Standard Time. Use these abbreviations only for presentation to 5e use, never for business logic, data storage, data exchange, logging, or debugging.

[Real time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) are named using a format of `Continent/Région`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
```

Adjust our moment into that zone. Same point on the timeline, but as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of that region.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the time of day.

```
LocalTime currentTimeOfDayKolkata = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
```

Parse the input time of day. No need to specify a formatting pattern as your input complies with the ISO 8601 standard used by default in the *java.time* classes.

```
LocalTime localTimeInput = LocalTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Do your comparison.

```
boolean isInputBeforeCurrentTimeOfDayKolkata = localTimeInput.isBefore( currentTimeOfDayKolkata ) ;
```

Notice that at no point in this code did we rely on the JVM’s current default time zone. Whether our computer is set to UTC time or to `Africa/Timbuktu` is irrelevant.

All this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.